# How to customize the open(+) and close (-) icons in jsTree

Tags: jstree

Is it possible to customize the open(-) and close(+) icons of jstree using the types plugin ? I can customize the node icons using types plugin,but was wondering, if I can do something same for expando icons also.

Answer (score 0):

The jstree icons are all css based sprites so you could always include your own CSS after the jstree.css where you have specific rewrites of the `ins.jstree-icon` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i can always do that by putting the css rules, but was wondering if there is any out of box support using the types plugin.